# access object property in handlebar contains '.'

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, handlebars.js

I am getting data from service in which  array of objects are coming like below:-

```
    [{
        title : 'Tilte 1',
        s.no : 1
     },
     {
        title : 'Tilte 2',
        s.no : 2   
     }
    ]
```

I have used handlebars templating to parse this data like below:-

```
{{#each this}}
   <div>
      <span>{{this.s.no}}</span>
      <h2>{{this.title}}</h2>
   </div>
{{/each}}
```

In the above I am not able to access the property('s.no'). In vanilla JavaScript we can access it like this['s.no'] but in handlebars it's not working.

Comment: {{this.[s.no]}} or {{this.["s.no"]}} try these two.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use special [] notation for properties that are not valid handlebar identifiers. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/va52u99v/).

```
{{#each this}}
   <div>
      <span>{{this.[s.no]}}</span>
      <h2>{{this.title}}</h2>
   </div>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Just curious--this does not need to be `this.['s.no']`?

Comment: I have an "[0]" in the object property ...how can I do this?